# How to redirect user to edit Home Screen widgets from Push notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, widget, sirikit

Spotify Home widget push notification
After click on "Add Widget" redirect user to edit home widget? How to do it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvqKj.png)

try to find any solution in internet, deep link any information. any information on Apple Documentation